# DropdownList is not taking the value of the selected index properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am using a `DropDownList` control and binding data from database. But after selecting an item from it, it always takes index 0 value.

Here is some code:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
{ 
    PQ.DropDownDepartment(drd_Department); 
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); 
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now); 
    PQ.DropDownUser(drd_Designation); 
    PQ.GetUser(drd_User, DesignID); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thankx in advance............

Comment: -1 This is a terrible question. Some effort on your behalf, please.

Comment: Edit the post and provide code where binding to dropdown list is being done.

Answer (score 1):

In Page Load Event, Bind the DropDownList like this

```
       if(!IsPostBack)
       {
            DropDownList.DataSource = dt;                   // dt is the DataTable
            DropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
            DropDownList.DataValueField = "ID";
            DropDownList.DataBind();               
       }
```

This is the sample code to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is you are binding/filling the `DropDownList` every time the page loads.

To solve this problem, try to check `Page.IsPostBack` before filling/binding it:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // bind/fill DropDownList
}
```

Comment: Hi Akram i am checking page ispostback before filling and also checked drd properties

Comment: if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            PQ.DropDownDepartment(drd_Department);
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
            PQ.DropDownUser(drd_Designation);
            PQ.GetUser(drd_User, DesignID);
        }

Comment: this is my postback condition and i want selected text of drd_user dropdown

Comment: and i am filling my dropdown from database, is there any drd property